# May I accept the answer?

Tags: support, user-accounts, accepted-answer

I asked [a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230574/solutions-of-equations-characterizing-a-complex-structure) without registration and Prof. Bryant answered it but I can not accept the answer because it is not contained in my account.

I would be grateful if you guide me to accept the answer. When I was asking the question I was not familiar with the Mathoverflow.

Or, I would be grateful if dear moderators accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer can *only* be accepted by the account that asked the question. 
Thus, you'd need to access the (old) account https://mathoverflow.net/users/86401/

If this is impossible for you, at first you cannot accept the answer.

But, it may still be possible for you to get the accounts merged (this could be a good idea regardless the present issue). To this end follow the instructions given at https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts

After the merge, you would be able to accept the answer in the usual way, by ticking the green checkmark next to the answer (as you did  already elsewhere).